# After 5 minutes of running , my libgdx game crashes and turns black

Tags: java, android, crash, libgdx

My app is working perfectly for the first five minutes but then after a period of time it crashes.`

```
package com.me.fixGame;

import java.util.Random;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;


import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.sun.jmx.snmp.tasks.Task;


public class fixGame implements ApplicationListener {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture trash; 
    Texture paper;
    SpriteBatch spritebatch;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 size;
    Vector2 size2;
    Vector2 pos;
    Rectangle bounds;
    Rectangle bounds2;
    float delay = 1; // seconds
boolean counted= false;
    int score = 3;
    String myScore;
    CharSequence str; // = myScore;
    BitmapFont font;
    boolean collision = false;
    @Override
    public void create() {  
        float delaySeconds = 1;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    trash = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));
    paper = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/paper1.jpg"));
    position = new Vector2(100, 50);
    pos = new Vector2(54, 14);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();

    size2 = new Vector2(trash.getWidth() ,trash.getHeight() );
    //size2.y = trash.getHeight();
    //size2.x = trash.getWidth();
    size = new Vector2(paper.getWidth() ,paper.getHeight());

    bounds= new Rectangle(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
    bounds2= new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
    public void update(){
        bounds.set(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
        bounds2.set(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);

        position.x = position.x -2- Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
    }




    @Override
    public void render() {

        if(bounds.overlaps(bounds2)){
            collision=true; 
            counted=true;
        }else{
            collision=false;
        }

        if(collision==true){

        } 

        if(pos.y<640){
            counted=false;
        } else if(pos.y > 640 && collision==false && counted==false){
            counted=true;
            score= score-1;
            myScore = "Your Score: " + score;
            str = myScore;
        }


        BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
          update();
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        pos.y=pos.y-12;
        if(pos.y<0){
            pos.y = 700;
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
              pos.x = randomGenerator.nextInt(500);
        }



        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(paper, pos.x, pos.y);
        batch.draw(trash, position.x, position.y);

        font.setColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f);
        font.draw(batch, str, 300,250);
                batch.end();

    }

     @Override  
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is going on, any help would be appreciated. Another thing i am wondering, eclipse, the program i am using to run my does not give any error yet out of no where my app crashes. 
Thanks in advance

`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your render loop, you're creating a new `BitmapFont` object each time the loop is run. Though libgdx manages memory for some objects, [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html) link says that `BitmapFont` needs to be disposed after it's done being used or your game will keep allocating memory for each new object. As you've already created `font` in the `create` method, you shouldn't need to instantiate it again. When you're done using it, you dispose of it in the `dispose()` method that you already have set up with something like `font.dispose()`.

Comment: Yup. As a rule, avoid calling new as much as possible after init has been done. Use pooling to re-use objects etc.

Comment: its a shame that libgdx doesnt put out an error message, when this happens... nevertheless this just solved an issue I had allday long!